# Expectation of Mahalanobis Distance and its logarithm

Tags: expected-value, t-distribution, mahalanobis

Suppose:

\begin{equation}
X \sim \mathcal{N}(X, \mu, \Sigma_x) \text{ st. } \Sigma_x \sim \mathcal{IW}(\Sigma_x; \Psi, v)
\end{equation}

Where $\mathcal{IW}$ is the Inverse-Wishart distribution. This [gives](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf) posterior predictive:

\begin{equation}
 X \sim \mathcal{T}\left(X, \mu, \frac{\Psi}{v - q + 1}\right)
\end{equation}

Given the above what is the expected Mahalanobis distance of $X$: $E[D]$?

Further, what is the expected log Mahalanobis distance of $X$: $E[\ln(D)]$?